# Profile Manager date format

Tags: macos, server.app, profile-manager

Can the date format used by Profile Manager be changed?

In the host OSX System Preferences control panel, the region is set to Australia and gives the example date of 5/01/2015 for the 5th of January. However the Profile Manager web interface uses US date format such as 01/05/2015.

Is there a way to set Profile Manager to use a more appropriate date format?